# Possible to have a hyperlink field that is NOT a formula field?

Tags: formula, formula-field, custom-field, hyperlink

Is it possible to set the value of a field such that it renders as a link in the UI (e.g. in a report column) WITHOUT the use of a formula field (for example, setting field value from Apex)?

Comment: you can use URL field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a custom field of type URL and populate it with Apex (or however). Here's the documentation: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=custom_field_types.htm&type=5